# How do I add an SQL connection in VSCode's "Run/Debug on Cloud Run Emulator" Build Settings

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am writing my first python 3.10 application in Visual Studio Code and aim to deploy that application to Cloud Run soon. I have a Cloud SQL database that stores my data for the application.

Before deploying I want to debug my application with the Cloud Code plugin for VSCode. The Cloud Code plugin has a convenient "Debug on Cloud Emulator" command that I can use for that purpose, but I am struggling to figure out how to add SQL connections in my Build Settings before running the Cloud Emulator.

Can somebody help me figure out the syntax for adding a Cloud SQL connection under the Advanced Service Settings?

[image]

Any examples / resources would be incredibly useful.

Thanks so much for your help up front!

Comment: Have you tried this format, `PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID`? Also, see this article on the [connection options for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview). You may need to setup a Cloud SQL Auth proxy to provide secure access to your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Hi Mabel - that looks super reasonable. 

Currently can't verify this works, since I'm running into another issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71389200/build-arm64-image-for-cloud-codes-debug-on-cloud-run-emulator-from-m1-mac), but will let you know as soon as I have that resolved. Do you want to submit this as a proper answer, so I can accept it later if correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Cloud SQL - Overview screen, you can find the connection name of your instance in this format:

```
PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID
```

Additionally, see this article on the [connection options for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview). You may also need to setup a [Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-auth-proxy) to provide secure access to your Cloud SQL instance.